# C# Returning the method in the same method

Tags: c#

example- I cant visualize how the below mentioned code would work assuming it had if else cases where one cases returned the int value and the rest returned the method() itself. Can someone explain what happens?

```
public static int method(){
    return method(); //how does this line work?
}
```

Comment: I don't think it does work. You can call a method and the method can return something but not itself. This method must return an `int`.

Comment: What you have created there is a perfect `System.StackOverflowException` generator

Comment: It’s called a recursive function and without some exit logic it’s going to fill up the call stack of your application

Answer (score 2):

This is called a recursion - a method that execute itself (could be multiple times).
One important thing about recursion is that it needs a stopping condition, otherwise it's an infinite recursion and will create a run time error.

The code you provided will cause an infinite recursion, so eventually (quite quick, but still eventually) you will get a `StackOverflowException`.

A classic example of recursion would be to calculate factorial (and in case you don't remember how it works, 5! = 5 * 4 * 3* 2 * 1).

So an implementation of a factorial recursive method would be something like this:

```
Int64 Factorial(int input)
{
    if(input < 0) 
    {
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Input must be 0 or higher.");
    }
    if(input < 2) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return input * Factorial(input - 1);
}
```

note: 0! = 1, and negative values are invalid for factorial, and the method returns a Int64 to avoid a mathematical overflow.

Now, let's say you call this method with the number 3:
`Factorial(3)` will return `3 * Factorial(3-1)`.
Similarly, `Factorial(2)` will return `2 * Factorial(2-1)`.
`Factorial(1)` will simply return `1`.
Putting it all together `Factorial(3)` will return `3 * 2 * 1` which is `3!`.

Answer (score 0):

The code would compile, but would most likely result in a stack overflow. You basically created a [recursive function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bftz997.aspx), without having an exit clause, which is bad. To answer your question, what would happen is:

1. You're calling the method.
2. The method calls "a method" to create a result, and that result happen to be itself.
3. Same as 2.
4. Same as 2.

...

Stack Overflow: You hit the maximum size of the stack.

(Note: I say most likely because you could augment the stack size, and run out of memory, or another thread could terminate first, etc.)